# Does $\lim_{x \to 4} \sqrt{x-4}$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

> Does $\lim_{x \to 4} \sqrt{x-4}$ exist?

The domain of the function is $[4,\infty)$ so does the left hand limit exist? And does the general limit exist?

Comment: Here is the behavior 0+i,0+1/2i,.....0+ni were n is very small. Therefore the imaginary part is slowly getting smaller and the limit is getting closer to 0 am I right?

Comment: Are you allowing your function to have a complex range? If not, this is problematic

Comment: Yes I am allowing, so am I right?

Comment: You are working with complex-valued functions in pre-calculus?

Comment: This is for calculus I, not sure what the teacher wants.

Comment: However he did teach us that  limit x->a f(x)=f(a) this is why I am assuming we are.

Comment: I have to assume you are not working with complex valued in calc I. In which case, $\sqrt{x-4}$ does not exist for any $x<4$. But you may want to check with your teacher to be sure.

Comment: So, as a technical matter, if you define the domain as $[4,+\infty)$, then yes, the limit exists. That's because "limit" is defined in terms of domain, although real functions often assume that the function is defined in a two-sided neighborhood. Ultimately, unfortunately, the answer is "depends on your definition."

Comment: the domain is $x\geq4$, we can not hence evaluate the function for $x<4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have never seen a definition of "limit" such that the limit does not exist here. Demanding a two-sided limit for a function not defined on one side seems so... artificial. (Also, to those waffling about the complex square root function, note that the limit exists there and is $0$ as well, regardless of what branch of the square root you pick.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro that was why I said "technically." And yeah, it would be a bad definition to require a 2-sided limit here. That doesn't mean the definition initially used doesn't assume 2-sided in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general limits does not exist by definition since you are limiting the domain to $x\geq4$.

The right hand limit exists, and it is 0.

Comment: Where I guess your definition of "general limit" has nothing to do with the general definition of limit in a topological space...